# Prove that all regular language is in L

Tags: regular-languages, space-complexity

im looking for a formal proof to demonstrate that all regular language is in L (logarithmic space).
I deduced that all regular languages has a DFA that accept them, so if i find a way to transform all DFA to a L-Space Turing Machine, i would be able to prove this.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: In fact, you don’t need any space at all.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I dont know if im understanding your answer, but you mean that i can prove this with a Turing Machine that only reads right? It is not necessary to write nothing in any tape.

Comment: That’s exactly right.

Comment: Every regular language has a finite state machine. You can turn that reasonably easy into a Turing machine.